# How to save the contour plot with .png format in python

Tags: save, contour

I want to save contour in python. I can't do it very well.
I used plt.savefig() but image is empty.
why?

```
!pip install tftb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as sio
from tftb.generators import atoms
import tftb
import cv2

mat = sio.loadmat('/content/drive/MyDrive/z5_25.mat')
signal = mat['z']
z = signal.T

images_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/image'

for i in range(122):
wvd = tftb.processing.WignerVilleDistribution(z[i])
wvd.run()
fig = plt.figure()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(1.5,1.5)
wvd.plot(kind = 'contour')
plt.savefig(f"{images_dir}/fig5_25_{i}.png")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but you can do so by replacing plt with wvd in the line

`wvd.plot(kind = 'contour') plt.savefig(f"{images_dir}/fig5_25_{i}.png")`

like this:

`wvd.plot(kind = 'contour') wvd.savefig(f"{images_dir}/fig5_25_{i}.png")`

it should work

Comment: Hello dear. thanks for answer. This answer dosen't work. 'wignervillDistribution ' object has not attribute 'savefig'.